# Is there a way to play a video as a form of response?

Tags: actions-on-google

For Actions on Google (building an Google Assistant app), is there a way to play a video (on phone - obviously cannot on Google Home with no screen!). I have it redirecting the user to a web browser at present but that takes them out of the Google Assistant app. Basic Card seems to be able to display a static image, not a video. I want to do responses using short video clips (not just static images with sound). Thanks!

Comment: I remember in the Number Genie example of Google, they played GIF and added sound to it, maybe you could try something similar. Their code is available [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks. I have a PNG with sound clips working already. I wanted to use a video instead of a static image. If you mean an animated GIF, I was a hesitant because I want lip syncing between the audio track and the video images. I was not sure how reliable showing an animated GIF would be with an audio file - i fear they would get out of sync (but I guess I can try...)

Comment: This is the only thing I thought of, but in the example it was only sound playing and not voice so I don't know how it will sounds like... Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for video right now. Audio is supported via MediaResponse - https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses.